# Updating photos in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
//--------------------javascript code------------------
var counter = 0;
var myImage = document.getElementById("newCode");
var photos = ["Face1.jpg", "Face2.jpg", "Face3.jpg", "Face4.jpg",
          "Face5.png", "Face6.png", "Face7.png"];

function changeImage () {
myImage.setAttribute("src", photos[counter]);
console.log(counter);
counter++;
if (counter >= photos.length)
    counter = 0;
}

setInterval(changeImage, 1000);

//----------------portion of HTML code--------------------
<span id="newCode">
        <img src="Face6.png" alt="Happy Face">
</span>
```

I'm new to javascript and trying to create code that will rotate the image displayed on a webpage with other images on the root folder. Problem is, my javascript code does not change the image with the others and only the one hardcoded into the html, "Face6.jpg" is displayed. 
I've checked and both files (index.html and the javascipt file) are linked correctly and the pictures for the array are in the right place (with correct spelling) in the root folder.
any ideas :(

Comment: Take a look at these lines: `var myImage = document.getElementById("newCode");` and `myImage.setAttribute("src", photos[counter]);`... You should affect `img`, not `span`.

Answer (score 0):

In your markup, the element with the ID "newCode" is **not** the image, it's the span containing the image.

Set an ID to your image element and use that instead:

```
<span>
    <img id="newCode" src="Face6.png" alt="Happy Face">
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:
http://jsbin.com/yuqerefowi/edit?html,js,console,output

```js
var counter = 0;
var myImage = document.getElementById("newCode").querySelector('img');
var photos = [
  "Face1.jpg", 
  "Face2.jpg", 
  "Face3.jpg", 
  "Face4.jpg",
  "Face5.png", 
  "Face6.png", 
  "Face7.png"
];

function changeImage () {
  myImage.setAttribute("src", photos[counter]);
  console.log(counter);
  counter++;
  if (counter >= photos.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }
}

setInterval(changeImage, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="newCode">
    <img src="Face6.png" alt="Happy Face">
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this line of javascript you are getting the `<span>`:

```
var myImage = document.getElementById("newCode");
```

And then trying to set the src attribute on it:

```
myImage.setAttribute("src", photos[counter]);
```

But you are actually looking for the image. What you can do is move the `id="newCode"` to:

`<img src="Face6.png" alt="Happy Face" id="newCode">`.

For example:

```js
var counter = 0;
var myImage = document.getElementById("newCode");
var photos = ["Face1.jpg", "Face2.jpg", "Face3.jpg", "Face4.jpg",
              "Face5.png", "Face6.png", "Face7.png"];

function changeImage() {
  myImage.setAttribute("src", photos[counter]);
  counter++;
  if (counter >= photos.length)
    counter = 0;
}
setInterval(changeImage, 1000);
```

```html
<span>
    <img src="Face6.png" alt="Happy Face" id="newCode">
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting `<span>` instead of `<img>`. To select inner `<img>` use:

```
var myImage=document.getElementById("newCode").getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
```